# Issue with running vbs script to execute ASP page through Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: asp-classic, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to execute an ASP page through a vbs file being triggered through Windows Task Scheduler.

The Task is completing without errors, however it completes immediately and is not updating my database.  If I run the ASP directly through the browser it does work correctly.  Ideas?

VBS File Code:

```
Dim url, xmlhttp

url = "http://localhost/adr-gateway/index-sysmon-cdDB.asp" ' ASP script to run

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false

xmlhttp.send ""

set xmlhttp = nothing
```

ASP File Code: Basically pulling data from 1 database and inserting it into another.

```
<%
'===================================================================================================================
'GET TOTAL NUMBER OF COMPLETED IMPORTS IN LAST HOUR
'===================================================================================================================
'MY SQL - DEFINE CONNECTION STRING & SPECIFY DB DRIVER
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=174.xx.xx.xxx; DATABASE=content_distributor; " &_
"UID=admin;PASSWORD=admin; PORT=3306 ; OPTION=3"
'CREATE INSTANCE OF ADO CONNECTION AND RECORDSET OBJECTS
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'OPEN CONNECTION TO DB
Connection.Open ConnString
'SQL STATEMENT TO QUERY DB
SQL = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) > NOW() AND job_type='IMPORT' AND state='COMPLETE'"
'OPEN RECORDSET AND RETURN SQL QUERY
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
'CHECK FOR RECORDS 
If Recordset.EOF Then 
msg = "No Records Present in Database"
Else 
'SET COUNT VARIABLE
importCount = 0
'IF THERE ARE RECORDS LOOP THROUGH THE DB
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
importCount = importCount + 1   
Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If
'CLOSE CONNECTION AND RECORDSET TO FREE UP CONNECTIONS
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing

'===================================================================================================================
'GET TOTAL NUMBER OF COMPLETED COPY JOBS IN LAST HOUR
'===================================================================================================================
'MY SQL - DEFINE CONNECTION STRING & SPECIFY DB DRIVER
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=174.75.78.150; DATABASE=content_distributor; " &_
"UID=admin;PASSWORD=admin; PORT=3306 ; OPTION=3"
'CREATE INSTANCE OF ADO CONNECTION AND RECORDSET OBJECTS
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'OPEN CONNECTION TO DB
Connection.Open ConnString
'SQL STATEMENT TO QUERY DB
SQL = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) > NOW() AND job_type='COPY' AND state='COMPLETE'"
'OPEN RECORDSET AND RETURN SQL QUERY
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
'CHECK FOR RECORDS 
If Recordset.EOF Then 
msg = "No Records Present in Database"
Else 
'SET COUNT VARIABLE
copyCount = 0
'IF THERE ARE RECORDS LOOP THROUGH THE DB
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
copyCount = copyCount + 1   
Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If
'CLOSE CONNECTION AND RECORDSET TO FREE UP CONNECTIONS
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing

'===================================================================================================================
'GET TOTAL NUMBER OF COMPLETED DELETE JOBS IN LAST HOUR
'===================================================================================================================
'MY SQL - DEFINE CONNECTION STRING & SPECIFY DB DRIVER
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=174.75.78.150; DATABASE=content_distributor; " &_
"UID=admin;PASSWORD=admin; PORT=3306 ; OPTION=3"
'CREATE INSTANCE OF ADO CONNECTION AND RECORDSET OBJECTS
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'OPEN CONNECTION TO DB
Connection.Open ConnString
'SQL STATEMENT TO QUERY DB
SQL = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) > NOW() AND job_type='DELETEALL' AND state='COMPLETE'"
'OPEN RECORDSET AND RETURN SQL QUERY
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
'CHECK FOR RECORDS 
If Recordset.EOF Then 
msg = "No Records Present in Database"
Else 
'SET COUNT VARIABLE
deleteCount = 0
'IF THERE ARE RECORDS LOOP THROUGH THE DB
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
deleteCount = deleteCount + 1   
Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If
'CLOSE CONNECTION AND RECORDSET TO FREE UP CONNECTIONS
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing

'===================================================================================================================
'GET TOTAL NUMBER OF FAILED JOBS IN LAST HOUR
'===================================================================================================================
'MY SQL - DEFINE CONNECTION STRING & SPECIFY DB DRIVER
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=174.75.78.150; DATABASE=content_distributor; " &_
"UID=admin;PASSWORD=admin; PORT=3306 ; OPTION=3"
'CREATE INSTANCE OF ADO CONNECTION AND RECORDSET OBJECTS
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'OPEN CONNECTION TO DB
Connection.Open ConnString
'SQL STATEMENT TO QUERY DB
SQL = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) > NOW() AND state='FAILED'"
'OPEN RECORDSET AND RETURN SQL QUERY
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
'CHECK FOR RECORDS 
If Recordset.EOF Then 
msg = "No Records Present in Database"
failedCount = "0"
Else 
'SET COUNT VARIABLE
failedCount = 0
'IF THERE ARE RECORDS LOOP THROUGH THE DB
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
failedCount = failedCount + 1   
Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If
'CLOSE CONNECTION AND RECORDSET TO FREE UP CONNECTIONS
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing



'Create an ADO connection object
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    'Set an active connection to the Connection object using a DSN-less connection
adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("DB/TS-GATEWAY.mdb")

'Create an ADO recordset object
Set rsAdd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Initialise the strSQL variable with an SQL statement to query the database
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CD_Health;"

'Set the cursor type we are using so we can navigate through the recordset
rsAdd.CursorType = 2

'Set the lock type so that the record is locked by ADO when it is updated
rsAdd.LockType = 3

'Open the recordset with the SQL query 
rsAdd.Open strSQL, adoCon

'Tell the recordset we are adding a new record to it
rsAdd.AddNew

'Add a new record to the recordset
rsAdd.Fields("importCount") = importCount
rsAdd.Fields("copyCount") = copyCount
rsAdd.Fields("deleteCount") = deleteCount
rsAdd.Fields("failedCount") = failedCount

'Write the updated recordset to the database
rsAdd.Update

'Reset server objects
rsAdd.Close
Set rsAdd = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Are you running the task with admin privileges?

Comment: Yes, the task is setup using the Administrator account

Comment: Doesn't matter if you created the task with the admin account, UAC still demands explicit verification - check the box which says "Run with highest privileges" if using the GUI to create task.

Comment: The task was created with the "Run with highest privileges" selected.

Comment: Add some logging, like writing to file, to see what exactly is going on.